# Event Handler and Navigation in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've been using the Event Handlers for a while, however i'm still puzzled concerning one issue related to those handlers especially when the handler is for the notification service.

When i navigate away from a page that has that event handler or even close the application, would the event still execute the relevant function when it is get triggered??

Thanks in advance,

Comment: what event handlers are you referring to?

Comment: i'm specifically referring to the following event handler related to push notifications: 
httpChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(...)

Answer (score 0):

It depends in what application lifecycle state it was during deactivation. If in a dormant - all event handles should still relevant. If app was tombstoned - you need to subscribe again.
Anyway, you should test your app in all conditions. In project settings you could check 'Tombstone app in debug during deactivation' (something like this) for debug this stuff.